# Should I still use jQuery to animations in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, transition, vuejs2

I currently have this piece of code inside my *methods* object in a component:

```
startImageAnimation() {
    $('.splash-image').fadeIn(1400, () => {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.splash-image').fadeOut(1400, () => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    $('.splash-screen').fadeOut(600);
                });
            });
        }, 1000);
    });
},
```

I really tried to figure a way to it using Vue transitions, but it just looks waaaaay too hard for something this simple to do using jQuery.

The real question here is: should I still code like this or should I take a different approach in these situations? The same for things like jQuery animate() or any other methods that jQuery makes a lot easier to do than with pure JS.

Thanks!

Comment: Of course, yes. Y can use any method for animation: pure css, js, jquery, vue transition. it is only your choice. And u cant make some animation with vue, only extra js

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I'm not totally sure if I should do it this way as I don't know if there's a better way (a more Vue way) to do it, that's what made me ask to make sure I'm not thinking the "jQuery way" and not the "Vue way". Thanks for the reply!

Comment: jquery is doing thins imperative way, but now you should think in declarative way, so mixing these two is not a good practice, but you can still do it if you want

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought @Giedrius, but I can't find a simple way out in this specific situation, could you provide any example regarding this transitions I want to make? Thanks!

Comment: You should load your script in this order 1. jQuery 2. vuejs 3. you application.js. As an example you could use requirejs / webpack for loading them, not sure how the cold implementation would look like. Although i would use a different approach, without jQuery. Read about vuejs tranistions https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html

Comment: Well.. that's the problem, transitions seems to be a lot, and I really mean a lot more complicated to achieve what I want with this function. I already tried to do it and it is much more simple to use fadeIn/fadeOut from jQuery than to do the same using CSS and Vue transitions, but it also doesn't seem very correct because of the imperative/declarative code thing. That's why I asked for an example, because maybe I'm missing something in Vue's transition, but I think I'm not. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you worry about declaring the animations for a class instead of just for the component element? If that is the case, you can replace `$('.splash-image')` to `$(this.$el).find('.splash-image')`, so it will only be applied to the DOM element of the current component instance.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer to animate not the element directly, but properties connected with it. For example, I might use such a piece of code:

`<div class="splash-screen" :style={opacity: splashOpacity}>`

where `splashOpacity` is a property of the object, returned by `data` method of Vue component.
And then I smoothly change `splashOpacity`, either vie`setInterval` or some sort of library like [Greensock](https://greensock.com/get-started-js#tweening-basics). Short example:

```
data () {
    return {
       splashOpacity: 0 
    }
},

startImageAnimation () {
    TweenLite.to(this, 1, {
       splashOpacity: 1
    }); 
}
```